# Как создать массив функций Python?

Tags: python

```
array1 = []
for i in range(10):
    array1.append(timeit.timeit("method1()", globals=globals(), number=10) / 10)
array2 = []
for i in range(10):
    array2.append(timeit.timeit("method2()", globals=globals(), number=10) / 10)
```

Как в данном коде создать массив функций method1(), method2(), чтобы можно было использовать только 1 for (ну и соответственно, 1 append)?
Уточню вопрос - можно ли написать что-то подобное:

```
function_array = [method1(), method2()]
array1 = []
for i in range(10):
    array1.append(timeit.timeit("function_array[0]", globals=globals(), number=10) / 10)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос:

```
array1 = []
for method in ['method1()', 'method2()']:
    for i in range(10):
        array1.append(timeit.timeit(method, globals=globals(), number=10) / 10)
```

Если нужно размещать результаты всё же в разные списки, то можно, к примеру, так:

```
from collections import defaultdict
arrays = defaultdict(list)
for method in ['method1()', 'method2()']:
    for i in range(10):
        arrays[method].append(timeit.timeit(method, globals=globals(), number=10) / 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно

```py
import timeit

def func1():
    print("1")

def func2():
    print("2")

mlist = [func1, func2]
array1 = [timeit.timeit(mlist[0], globals=globals(), number=10) / 10 for i in range(10)]
```